# Addtocart in custom phtml executes multiple time when browser is refreshed?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I have a button which add product to cart programatically.I execute but when the browser is refreshed it execute again.Give solution. It is not a submit button.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btncart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('mycustommodule/custommodule/savetocart/',array('visitorid'
=> $visitorid))?>')"><span></span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></button>
```